# How to upgrade a production server's Ruby version?

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

We are using Ruby 1.8.7 in dev and production with various version of rails.  We'd like to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2.  What is the process for upgrading to ruby 1.9.2 in production without taking existing websites using ruby 1.8.7 down?  We are using apache + passenger, but no RVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apache as a proxy only and run individual web servers for each project (like passenger-standalone or unicorn). You can start the servers during deployment and redirect the vhosts to the individual ports. If you manage to set up the environment for each project to point to it's own ruby version you won't even need rvm.

Comment: sad that this the only way, but i'm marking yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run both versions simultaneously, you are in for some fun, since most solutions such as passenger can only run one version of ruby at a time.  I got around this myself by using rvm to install multiple versions, and let apache/passenger run one version, and nginx/passenger run another version.  Then I set sites that need the nginx/passenger version to proxypass through apache to it.

Comment: i actually just want to upgrade ruby entirely, but safely, not run two versions.

Comment: For testing purposes, I'd recommend setting up a test server in a virtual machine to make sure all the apps upgrade correctly...  and then you could *still* use RVM to upgrade, as that would leave the system ruby alone and a system update won't affect the rest of your apps.   RVM and Passenger both have lots of documentation on how to install.